# Find the first and the last row index of nan values in a pandas dataframe if the number of consecutive nans hit the threshold N for a given column?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

There is a pandas dataframe with 80 rows and 6 columns. Some columns have nan values in them. Let's say that if the number of consecutive nan values in a given column exceeds 10, then we have to do something about the values of those chunks of nans. So, my question is how to extract the row indices corresponding to the start and the end of these big chunks of nans?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### setup

Let's assume the following example input:

```
np.random.seed(3)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice([0,1], p=[0.7, 0.3], size=(80,6)))
df = df.mask(df.eq(0))
df.head(15)
```

input:

```
      0    1    2    3    4    5
0   NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN  1.0  1.0
1   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
3   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
4   NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0
5   1.0  NaN  1.0  1.0  NaN  NaN
6   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
7   NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN
8   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
9   NaN  NaN  1.0  1.0  NaN  NaN
10  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
11  NaN  NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN
12  1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
13  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0
14  NaN  NaN  1.0  NaN  1.0  1.0
...
79  1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

#### computing the consecutive NaN length

You can compute a mask with `isna`, then generate a group with a combination of `mask.ne(mask.shift())`, `cumsum` and mask it with `where`. Finally apply a `groupby` transformation with `'size'` to get the number of consecutive NaNs:

```
mask = df.isna()

df_na_sizes = (mask.ne(mask.shift()).cumsum()
                   .where(mask)
                   .apply(lambda c: c.groupby(c).transform('size'))
               )
```

output:

```
      0     1    2    3     4    5
0   5.0   NaN  5.0  5.0   NaN  NaN
1   5.0   3.0  5.0  5.0  13.0  3.0
2   5.0   3.0  5.0  5.0  13.0  3.0
3   5.0   3.0  5.0  5.0  13.0  3.0
4   5.0   NaN  5.0  5.0  13.0  NaN
5   NaN  12.0  NaN  NaN  13.0  8.0
6   6.0  12.0  3.0  1.0  13.0  8.0
7   6.0  12.0  3.0  NaN  13.0  8.0
8   6.0  12.0  3.0  1.0  13.0  8.0
9   6.0  12.0  NaN  NaN  13.0  8.0
10  6.0  12.0  1.0  5.0  13.0  8.0
11  6.0  12.0  NaN  5.0  13.0  8.0
12  NaN  12.0  2.0  5.0  13.0  8.0
13  2.0  12.0  2.0  5.0  13.0  NaN
14  2.0  12.0  NaN  5.0   NaN  NaN
    ...
79  NaN   1.0  2.0  5.0   4.0  1.0
```

#### using our mask for filtering

Now you can use this to select by group size, for example let's replace NaNs with 'XX' if the consecutive NaNs are equal or greater to 10:

```
>>> df.mask(df_na_sizes.ge(10), 'XX')
      0    1    2    3    4    5
0   NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN  1.0  1.0
1   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   XX  NaN
2   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   XX  NaN
3   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   XX  NaN
4   NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN   XX  1.0
5   1.0   XX  1.0  1.0   XX  NaN
6   NaN   XX  NaN  NaN   XX  NaN
7   NaN   XX  NaN  1.0   XX  NaN
8   NaN   XX  NaN  NaN   XX  NaN
9   NaN   XX  1.0  1.0   XX  NaN
10  NaN   XX  NaN  NaN   XX  NaN
11  NaN   XX  1.0  NaN   XX  NaN
12  1.0   XX  NaN  NaN   XX  NaN
13  NaN   XX  NaN  NaN   XX  1.0
14  NaN   XX  1.0  NaN  1.0  1.0
...
79  1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: This is amazing! Thank you, I was working with for loops and if statements and I was never able to achieve what this code is doing. Not just the elegance but also the brevity of the code is amazing.

Comment: @Ash glad it helped! I use pandas a lot and I almost never need loops, so when you think you need a loop, think harder, there is a good chance that there is a faster solution without loop ;)

Comment: @mozaway, thank you! just curious! is there anyway to put "XX" only for those consecutive nans who complete size of 10 chunks? meaning if there are 28 consecutive nans in column "4" starting from row 0, then only fill the first 20 and leave the rest (8) as nan? In other words, I am only interested to fill up completely nan chunks of 10!